# hibernate indexing time based UUID

Tags: performance, hibernate, time, indexing, uuid

We have currently a  postgresql database using UUID as a primary key. We are using hibernate as a ORM tool in order to manage the postgresql with the dialect
“org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect”

I have read an article (http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid) that there is a way to increase the read/write performance if  "Time based" / "Version 1" UUIDs  are used. In order to do that we need to  rearrange the 3rd part of the UUID i.e. rearrange it in a way that the 3rd part becomes the first one. Then we are getting a number  that increases nicely over time. The idea is to place the index on such table, thus we can make the IO even faster

Now the question is : Has anybody tried using this  in a table with hundreds of million rows and if so does this change make sense. I mean UUID's is an idea not discovered today and I bet there is a reason why this has NOT been done so far.

How  can I produces such UUID's  using hibernate,  there are 5 types and as far as I understand none of them produce those time based rearranged  UUID's .  How should the field "private UUID studentId;" look like i.e. which annotations should be used in order to tell hibernate to generate such an UUID. 
import java.util.UUID;

```
@Id 
@Index
@Column(name="STUNDENT_ID")
@NotNull
private UUID studentId;
```